# Windows 8 "Desktop" Application

Tags: windows-8

The Metro/Modern UI apps are stored in `%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps`, except there isn't one for the `Desktop` tile.

Where is this one, is it a special case somehow - where is the manifest / XML that describes this tile?

Answer (score 3):

I used Process Monitor to watch what happened when I moved the Desktop tile on the Start screen, and discovered some writing to the following file:

`%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\appsFolder.itemdata-ms`

There's a lot of interesting stuff in `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\WinX` as well.

Answer (score 1):

The Desktop tile is a link stored in

> **%programdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs**

The Filename is

> **desktop.lnk**

The Windows App Store link (store.lnk) is stored there, too.

Answer (score 0):

The Desktop is not an app, it is **explorer.exe**, an integral part of the OS.

It is located in the **C:\Windows** folder

Comment: Thanks Moab - it has a tile however, so there must be a manifest that describes the tile somewhere?

Comment: Possibly, but it could be buried in the explorer exe itself or called by the exe. There is an "AppRepository" folder located at C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows, but is permission locked.

Comment: Hmmm.   Doesn't seem to be in there either.