# Desktop preview on start screen tile

Tags: windows-8, desktop, start-screen

Is it possible to display a preview of the desktop on the desktop tile, like you get when switching to it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desktop tile by design shows the desktop background. Changing this is not an option in Windows 8 and would require changes to the actual tile manifest. The following question might help you, but at the time an answer has not been found:

> [Windows 8 “Desktop” Application](https://superuser.com/questions/491390/windows-8-desktop-application)

Comment: Hmm interesting, so it seems some could make a screensaver that, when in the modern ui shows the desktop.

Comment: Looks more like the desktop's background to me, not the screensaver.

Comment: You're right, I mixed up the words. I did mean desktop background - sorry!

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense. All we need to do then is get something that saves the wallpaper and sets it to a screenshot when we go to the Modern UI, then restores the wallpaper when we go back to the desktop! :/

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: Or maybe an app which can take regular screenshots of the desktop and display on its live tile? (Would this sort of operation even be allowed though? If so, I'm sure we'll see an app along those lines sooner or later.)

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett I think the more likely solution would be reverse-engineering the desktop app and adding in the logic you need.